# Converting a date in to a different type of date using javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I need to convert a date like this one: `Fri Jul 28 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)` Into a date like this: `2023-07-26`  or viceversa using javascript, is it possible or impossible?

Comment: Not sure how Jul 28 would ever turn into `07-26`…!?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
const inputDate = "Fri Jul 28 2023 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)";
const dateObject = new Date(inputDate);
const year = dateObject.getFullYear();
const month = String(dateObject.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0');
const day = String(dateObject.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
const resultDate = `${year}-${month}-${day}`;

console.log(resultDate); // Output: "2023-07-28"
```

Reverse:

```
const inputDate = "2023-07-28";
const dateObject = new Date(inputDate);
const options = { weekday: 'short', month: 'short', day: '2-digit', year: 'numeric', timeZoneName: 'short' };
const resultDate = dateObject.toLocaleString('en-US', options);

console.log(resultDate);
```

Comment: Dates in the format YYYY-MM-DD are parsed as UTC, so for systems with timezone west of Greenwich, the "reverse" solution will produce a date that is 1 day earlier. Also, `dateObject.toLocaleString('en-US', options)` will not produce a result the same as the original timestamp. `timeZoneName: 'short'` will produce different results in different implementations and depending on the default language..

Comment: @RobG I'll be glad to see your solution.